# CDN citizen living abroad in one country and working remotely for another

Tags: taxes, immigration, freelance, canadian-citizens

Need help with my situation:

- Canadian citizen
- Currently living and working in Africa for a company
- Offered a part-time position to work remotely for a UK company.
- Wishes to **remain** working in Africa, and work part-time **remotely** for UK company

Questions:

### - How do I invoice the UK company. Do I need to register as a sole-proprietor as a Canadian?

Comment: If you're living in Africa, wouldn't you need to register as self employed / sole-proprietor in that country?